# Beamer: \abovedisplayskip inactive in sublist?

Tags: beamer, lists, vertical-alignment

A weird mechanism is observed below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0ex
\belowdisplayskip=0ex
\frame{\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos \pi=-1
\end{equation}
text text text text text text text
   \begin{itemize}
   \item text text text text text text text
   \begin{equation}
   \cos \pi=-1
   \end{equation}
   text text text text text text text
   \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the new `\abovedisplayskip=0pt` seems to be ignored in the second level `itemize` list. It seems to be related to the fontsize in the lists but is a bit annoying as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every font size changing command resets the skips around math displays. Second level `itemize` use `\small`, so you need to change it; also `\normalsize` and, possibly, other font size changing commands.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\normalsize{%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt
  \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt
  \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
}
\appto\small{%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt
  \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt
  \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos \pi=-1
\end{equation}
text text text text text text text
   \begin{itemize}
   \item text text text text text text text
   \begin{equation}
   \cos \pi=-1
   \end{equation}
   text text text text text text text
   \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to do it only in selected slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\zerodisplayskips}{%
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt
  \belowdisplayskip=0pt
  \abovedisplayshortskip=0pt
  \belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
}
\newcommand{\removedisplayskips}{%
  \appto\normalsize{\zerodisplayskips}
  \appto\small{\zerodisplayskips}
  \zerodisplayskips
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\removedisplayskips
\begin{itemize}
\item text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
\cos \pi=-1
\end{equation}
text text text text text text text
   \begin{itemize}
   \item text text text text text text text
   \begin{equation}
   \cos \pi=-1
   \end{equation}
   text text text text text text text
   \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you think it should be reported as a bug?

Comment: @pluton What bug?

Comment: The fact that we have to handle displayskips per font size? I know it is not a real bug but it seems a bit annoying here. Maybe the displayskips mechanism should be global and not just per font size.

Answer (score 2):

Uee

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

and it should be ok. If it is not possible use:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\item}{%
  \abovedisplayskip=0ex
  \belowdisplayskip=0ex}
\makeatother
```

or redefine `itemize`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other possibility? Because `enumitem` breaks most of my beamer list settings.

Comment: see my edit ...  It may be possible that you also nee `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\below...`